# Is compiled to binary's user mode program showing logical address or linear address in Windows

Tags: c, windows, memory-management

I was reading **Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual**.

I understand that before going through paging, the logical address will first have to be converted to linear address, and from linear address it will goes through paging table in order to generate the ultimate physical address.

My question is that, if we run the C code below, the address of variable `a` that is printed, is it a logical address or a linear address?

I know that Windows 10 64-bit is currently using long mode and so the logical address and linear address are the same, but the question I have in mind is:


*Is the address we are seeing in user mode program is logical address or it's the linear address that has gone through the global descriptor table translation?*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int a = 50;
  printf("%p", &a);
  return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: If the system uses segmentation, then yes the address in your user-space address will be a "logical" address.

Comment: Your program always deals in logical addresses.  So that's what `printf` will print.  The logical-to-physical translation happens at a much deeper level, quite invisible to your program.

Comment: The key is that phrase *user mode program*.  One of the defining features of user mode is that the OS and the MMU are busy mapping the program's logical addresses to physical ones, based on the particular process's memory map.  But once the OS has set up that memory map, the address translation is done in hardware (which is what I meant by "much deeper level").  The C code, or the generated assembly language code, or the debugger if you're running that way — they all deal exclusively in logical addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has not used segmented memory since it stopped being 16-bit. Or to put it a different way, the GDT just spans from 0 to the end of linear space in 32-bit Windows.

All this is irrelevant when asking about C because it has no knowledge of such details. To answer we must ignore the C abstract machine and look directly at Windows on x86.

If we imagine your code running in 16-bit Windows, taking the address of a local variable is going to give you the offset into the segment. This is 16-bits. A FAR address on the other hand is 32-bits of information, the segment and the offset. The Windows function `lstrlen` (l for long?) takes a FAR address and can compute the length of a string coming from anywhere. The `strlen` C function might just use a plain `char*` pointer; just the segment offset. Your C compiler might support different memory models (tiny, small, compact, medium, large), giving you access to more memory, perhaps even FAR pointers. Classic DOS .com files use the tiny model, there are no segments, just a maximum of 64 KiB for all code and data. Other models might separate code and data in different segments.

In 32 and 64 bit Windows the logical and linear addresses are the same but if you have to think of it in terms of your graphic, `%p` is going to print the logical address. `print` is not going to ask the CPU/OS to translate the address in any way.